# setItemChecked not working on Gingerbread

Tags: android, listview, selector, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am using the following selector to change the appearance of text in a listView item:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> <!-- activated -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#FFFFFFFF" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#FF000000" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

The entire selector works fine on later versions of Android (ICS, JB), but on Gingerbread, while the pressed_state item is being applied correctly, when I call setItemChecked on the listView, the state_checked item isn't applied.

The code I am using to set the item is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    for (int index = 0; index < measureList.size(); index++)
    {
        if (measureList.get(index).getId() == appContext.getMeasureId())
        {
            getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
        }
    }
}
```

and the xml used to set the selector is this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_thumb"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/selected_text_selector"
        />
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I haven't yet tested it out on versions of Android between GB and ICS, but will edit this post as soon as I do.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742979/how-to-get-a-android-listview-item-selector-to-use-state-checked

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Sorry for being so quick to shoot your idea down Voicu - it turns out it let me to a solution (below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little searching, it seems to me the reason that the `state_checked` isn't expressed pre-Honeycomb is the fact that the `setActive` method on `View` is not available before API level 11. This means that the checked state is not propagated to the child views of my layout.

**THE KEY:**

1. Swap the `TextView` for a `CheckedTextView`
2. Propagate the checked state from the parent view to the children

1) Was a simple switch in the XML, and for 2) I modified the code in the answer linked to by Voicu to give the following:

```
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable
{
    private boolean checked = false;

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = {
            R.attr.state_checked
    };

    @Override
    protected void dispatchSetPressed(boolean pressed)
    {
        super.dispatchSetPressed(pressed);
        setChecked(pressed);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++)
        {
            View view = getChildAt(index);
            if (view.getClass().toString().equals(CheckedTextView.class.toString()))
            {
                CheckedTextView checkable = (CheckedTextView)view;
                checkable.setChecked(checked);
                checkable.refreshDrawableState();
            }
        }
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        checked = !checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        return super.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is R.attr.state_checked defined? Should it be in my own package or is it really the android.R.attr.state_checked attribute? It would be helpful to see your imports or perhaps your associated attr.xml file if it needs to be in my own package.

Comment: @Baron: I'm afraid that since it's been a long time since asking this,  I can no longer remember where this code was used and can't find the imports or xml files for you, but I'm almost certain I'm referring to android.R.attr.state_checked as you thought.

Good point on the imports though. I'll be sure to include them in future questions!

Comment: @sleeke for future questions: yes, the attribute used is "android.R.attr state_checked.". Tested and worked perfectly. Thank you!