# GingerBread ListView not working

Tags: android, listview, android-2.3-gingerbread

This code works on KitKat, but on GingerBread it doesn't.
On list pressing or selection, I don't get different selected color on GingerBread, 
but on KitKat it works fine.

List_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

 </selector>
```

list_item_bg_normal

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/list_background_pressed" />

 </shape>
```

list_item_bg_pressed

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/list_background" />

 </shape>
```

my listvie

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_accounts"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp"      />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#61269e"
            android:text="A/C Number"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#61269e"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: activated does not exist in gingerbread.

Comment: so with what do i replace it?

Comment: @user3278732 Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17073595/1408986 Worked for me!